# How to create our own dynamic array class in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was trying yo create my own array class (similar to std::vector) just for fun but there is some problem...
The Array class code itself works and compiles successfully but throws an error if i try to instantiate an object of Array class.

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename type, int size>
class Array
{
 private:
 type _mArray[size] = new type[size];
 public:
 int Access(int index)
 {
  return _mArray[index];
 }
 int Len()
 {
   return size;
 }
 void Insert(int index, type val)
 {
  _mArray[index] = val;
 }
 ~Array()
 {
  delete[] _mArray; 
 }
};//All code above compiles successfully

int main()
{
  Array<int, 2> name; //this line throws an error
}
```

I am a bit new to C++ so if someone can explain then I will be very thankful....

Btw here is the error
*Array initializer must be an initializer list*

Comment: If you want to have a dynamic array like std::vector, don't make size a template parameter. Also type of size should not be an int but std::size_t (avoids having to check for index < 0). Check the input indices against the size of the actual array (or you can get out of bound access).

Comment: *The Array class code itself works* -- `int main() { Array<int, 2> name; Array<int, 2> name2; name = name2; }` -- Double deletion error at runtime.  You still have work today to get this code to actually be useful.

Comment: Look more like [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (fixed size array) than [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (dynamic size array).

Answer (score 2):

```
type _mArray[size] = new type[size];
```

The template instantiates with: `type` is `int`, and `size` is 2. Therefore, this becomes:

```
int _mArray[2] = new int[2];
```

This obviously does not make much sense. If you put this, verbatim, in your `main()` your C++ compiler will also serve you with the same complaint.

It's clear that the intent here is, simply:

```
type _mArray[size];
```

And nothing else.

P.S. Now, let's go back and reread what the suffering C++ compiler was struggling to communicate here:

> Array initializer must be an initializer list

`int _mArray[2]` is, obviously, an array. There's an `=` stuck after it. Ok, this must be array initialization. How do you initialize an array in C++? With a braced initialization list, of course. This would be something like this, for example:

```
int _mArray[2]={1, 2};
```

The C++ compiler saw nothing of that kind, and was trying to tell you that.

Comment: Very good explanation +1

Comment: destructor has to be fixed/removed then :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename type, int size>
class Array
{
 private:
 type * _mArray ;
 public:
 int Access(int index)
 {
  return _mArray[index];
 }
 int Len()
 {
   return size;
 }

 Array()
 {
   _mArray = new type[size];
 }
 ~Array()
 {
  delete[] _mArray; 
 }
 int& operator[](int index){
    return _mArray[index];
 }
};//All code above compiles successfully

int main()
{
  Array<int, 2> name; 
  name[0] = 1024;
  name[1] = 100;

  for(int i= 0; i< name.Len(); i++)
  {
     std::cout<< name[i] << std::endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: And what? Just code dump?

Comment: [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to build using the following minimal change:

```
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@ template<typename type, int size>
 class Array
 {
  private:
- type _mArray[size] = new type[size];
+ type* _mArray;
  public:
  int Access(int index)
  {
@@ -18,6 +18,10 @@ class Array
  {
   _mArray[index] = val;
  }
+ Array()
+ {
+  _mArray = new type[size]; 
+ }
  ~Array()
  {
   delete[] _mArray;
```

Basically, you should be initializing the array in your constructor, and store a pointer to it as a class member.  The following code builds:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename type, int size>
class Array
{
 private:
 type* _mArray;
 public:
 int Access(int index)
 {
  return _mArray[index];
 }
 int Len()
 {
   return size;
 }
 void Insert(int index, type val)
 {
  _mArray[index] = val;
 }
 Array()
 {
  _mArray = new type[size]; 
 }
 ~Array()
 {
  delete[] _mArray; 
 }
};//All code above compiles successfully

int main()
{
  Array<int, 2> name; //this line throws an error
}
```

Comment: [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) broken.